# to draw sphere using patch in matlab, is it possible?

Tags: matlab, patch

i'd like to draw sphere using 'patch' function in Matlab.

in function 'patch'
"vertex=[~~]" in this part, how to choice the point...

And i wonder if possible to draw sphere using 'patch function'..

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have coordinates for points on the sphere in `x`, `y`, and `z`, as obtained by

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;
```

Then faces and vertices of a patch object can be obtained using [surf2patch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf2patch.html):

```
fvc = surf2patch(x,y,z);
```

Finally, it can be plotted:

```
patch('Faces', fvc.faces, 'Vertices', fvc.vertices, 'FaceColor', [1, 0, 0])
```

This approach can be generalized to any function data.

Comment: Just as extra, you don't even need to separate the values, you can pass fvc structure directly to `patch` as `patch(fvc,'FaceColor',[1,0,0])`

Comment: so good information !! and..why don't need to separate the values..?

Comment: @jeong That's what is referred to as [`patch(S)`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#busd9x8-1) in the documentation.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez  First so sorry i using this program first..if i use vector, can i draw sphere? same as using patch.... i want to fix center point and there is a constant distance from the center.

Comment: @jeong take a look at [`sphere`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html). The generated sphere has radius 1, so you can just scale the coordinates to match the length of your vector. The examples show how to move the sphere in space.